# How to create a plot like the one shown

Tags: fonts, graphics, plot

My program is currently making plots which look like [image]

However, I would like to produce a plot with font and plot axes which looks exactly like the following:

[image]

I do not care about the actual data represented within the plot. Notice the difference in the fonts between the two plots' labels and the different font for the numbers. I want to know if anyone may have knowledge of the type of font.

Comment: We don't deal with python here? This is off-topic.

Comment: It is not a python question, in particular. It is, if you want, a calligraphy question. I simply want to know if anyone may help me identify the plot aesthetic. Indeed, it is wholly relevant, for many papers in LaTeX are produced with such plots.

Comment: What is your question, can you clarify it by editing?

Comment: Yes, I have done so

Comment: see http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples#dotError